# Discount disappears after changing payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart-price-rules

we created coupon code, so that that coupon should not work if customer select **"Cash on delivery"** payment method.

[image]

customer will apply coupon in cart page & go to checkout and select **Prepaid payment method** and no issue here, he can see Discount as below image. [ -139]

[image]

Again customer will  go back to "Payment information" step & he selects **Cash on delivery** and go to "Order review" step, he dont see any discount, thats fine.....

[image]

But customer become mad and again he go back to "Payment information" & select **Prepaid payment method** and come to "Order review" step, now he see the Devil that **he dont see any discount...**.

This issue is happening only for new customers in site, for old customers there is no issue....

**log errors** in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php

Notice: Array to string conversion  in

```
$send .= $param . '=' . $value . "\r\n";}
```

Notice: Undefined variable: datasend in

```
$datasend .= substr($send, 5, -1);
```

Edit 2

[image]

Comment: you can check in this [demo site](http://sbdevelopers.kidsdial.com:81/better-together.html) with dummy coupon code : `dummy`

Comment: also you need to enter `560043` to see `cash on delivery` as payment method....

Comment: @Nits please enter `560043` under zip code , coupon code name is `dummy`

Comment: plz disable cache for some time :)

Comment: @Nits its done cache disabled now.....

Comment: I got that issue Lets chat ?

Comment: @Nits please join : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53371/please-help-me

Comment: Have you check $value or $param is not array. may be one of the value is array at that time you have faced this time of error.

Comment: @Rakesh I have no idea how to check `$value or $param` is array or not, can you please guide me......

Comment: Please show your full code of above file?

Comment: @Rakesh here is full code of Onepage.php : http://pastebin.com/8zFBBzz8 , please check once......

Comment: i dont see any variable $send or $datasend in your code

Comment: @Rakesh sorry, i replaced original default magento file and forgotten to replace it, please check cuurent code here : http://pastebin.com/fkA734mf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below code in your file at line no.  647 ,
you had forgot to define variable for $datasend,

```
$sendNewStr = '';
 foreach ($send as $param=>$value) {
    $sendNewStr .= $param . '=' . $value . "\r\n";
 }
 $datasend = '';
$datasend .= substr($sendNewStr, 5, -1);
```

Comment: i added your code `$sendNewStr = '';` & I tested it many times, still issue is there.....

Comment: which error are you faced now?

Comment: in log i am getting `Notice: Undefined index: p ` in app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml - `<?php if($_GET['p']<=1){?>` , full code : http://pastebin.com/F6t0RDcE

Comment: if(isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])){ if($_GET['p']<=1) {} } keep your code in condition

Comment: updated code, still i can see same errors in log.....

Comment: from where you have set 'p' variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53542/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-rakesh).

Answer (score 2):

Before digging into the overall code base, one key statement that you made above made me think that we should look at the overall Shopping Cart Price Rule:

- Existing users have no problems using the rule.
- New users are not seeing the discount.

Have you checked to make sure that in the Shopping Cart Price Rule, you rule has everyone selected?

[image: Shopping Cart Price Rule, with only logged in users]

Here's the same rule, but with all customer groups selected:

[image: Shopping Cart Price Rule, with ALL users selected]

Hopefully this fixes the issue?

If this doesn't fix the issue, I'd recommend testing out the shopping cart price rule on a blank, fresh instance of the Magento 1.x site to see if it works there.

If it does work on a blank, fresh instance, it's likely a code modification or an extension conflict.

I'd recommend running a Magento code audit on the site to see if you have any core file changes or overrides, such as the one here: [Free Magento Code Audit Tool](http://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-development/free-magento-code-audit-report/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i checked with configuration, its correct..... i will check other tips suggested by you......

Answer (score 1):

Try to perform a reindex and secondly, use native theme (rwd).

Comment: Thanks, i am reindexing now for 20 million products......

Comment: `rwd` is not available, we checked with `default theme`  in another replica [site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/stunning-bike-racer-apple-iphone-7-plus-phone-case.html) , but issue is still there....

Comment: reindexing done, still issue is there.....

Comment: Try to re-check your promo rules, conditions, validations, active websites and other stuff related.

Comment: let me update question with full images......

Comment: please check `edit2` part in question.....